# Запись адрес слов из строки

Tags: c, алгоритм, строки, рекурсия

```
 int string_split(char* string,char ** array_results){
    static int word_count;
        if( string == 0){ return word_count; }//конец строки
        if( string-1 == 0){ //если предыдущий символ 0, то это слово
                *array_results = &string;
                array_results++;
                word_count++;
            }
        if(*string == ' '){ string = 0; }
    return string_split(++string,array_results);
    }
```

Нужно разделить строку на слова и в результате получить массив указателей на слова.
Почему-то выдает ошибку

```
warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
             *array_results = &string
```

Comment: Правильно, зачем искать лёгких путей в виде `strtok()` :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Начнем с того, что функция не имеет смысла и к тому же имеет неопределенное поведение, даже если бы код компилировался.

Так, в этом фрагменте кода

```
    if(*string == ' '){ string = 0; }
return string_split(++string,array_results);
```

значение указателя `string` устанавливается равным 0. А затем в рекурсивном вызове функции это значение указателя увеличивается на 1. В результате при следующем вызове функции, указатель `string` равен 1, и происходит обращение к памяти по этому недопустимому адресу.

Далее в этом предложении

```
if( string-1 == 0){ 
    ^^^^^^^^
```

сравниваются не символ строки с 0, а значение указателя `string - 1` с нулем.

Что касается ошибки компилятора, то она в контексте сказанного уже не имеет большого значения, так как в любом случае данная функция не верная. Тем не менее ошибка связана с данным предложением

```
*array_results = &string;
```

так как левый операнд имеет тип `char *`, в следствии разыменования указателя типа `char **`, а правый операнд имеет тип `char **`в следствии применения оператора взятия адреса к объекту типа `char *`

Но, как я уже написал, это не имеет большого значения, так как вам надо полностью переписать функцию заново.

Функция может выглядеть следующим образом, как показано в приведенной ниже демонстрационной программе.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>


size_t string_split( const char *s, char ***a )
{
    static int count = 0;
    size_t n = 0;

    if ( s )
    {
        if ( *s == '\0' )
        {
            count = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            if ( !isblank( ( unsigned char )*s ) && 
                 ( count == 0 || isblank( ( unsigned char )s[-1] ) ) )
            {
                ++count;
                n = 1;

                char **tmp = realloc( *a, count * sizeof( char * ) );

                if ( tmp ) 
                {
                    *a = tmp;
                    ( * a )[count -1] = ( char * )s;
                }
                else 
                {
                    free( *a );
                    *a = NULL;
                    count = 0;
                    n = -1;
                }
            }               

            if ( n != -1 )
            {
                size_t i = string_split( s + 1, a );
                n = i == -1 ? i : n + i;
            }
        }           
    }

    return n;
}

int main( void ) 
{
    char *s1 = "Hello function string_split";
    char **a = NULL;

    size_t n = string_split( s1, &a );

    if ( n != -1 )
    {
        for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) puts( a[i] );

        free( a );

        a = NULL;
    }

    char *s2 = "A B C D E F G";

    n = string_split( s2, &a );

    if ( n != -1 )
    {
        for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) puts( a[i] );

        free( a );

        a = NULL;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль:

```
Hello function string_split
function string_split
string_split
A B C D E F G
B C D E F G
C D E F G
D E F G
E F G
F G
G
```

Answer (score 1):

Судите сами:

```
*array_results = &string
```

`array_results` имеет тип `char**`, т.е. `*array_results` имеет тип `char*`.

`string` имеет тип `char*`, так что `&string` имеет тип `char**`.

так что эти типы и в самом деле совершенно разные...

А вообще - я бы делал так (если, конечно, нужна рекурсия, слова разделены пробелами etc etc...):

```
int string_split(char* str, char ** array_results)
{
    if(str == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    while(*str == ' ') ++str;

    if (*str == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    *array_results++ = str;

    while(*str && *str != ' ') ++str;

    if (*str == 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        *str = 0;
    }
    return 1 + string_split(str+1,array_results);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

И до кучи:

```
static int word_count;
  if( string == 0){ return word_count; }//конец строки
  /* ... */
```

При первом обращении значение `word_count` действительно будет `0`. А при последующих? Оно будет начинаться со значения, вычисленного на предыдущем вызове функции. И то, что оно используется в рекурсии, от этого никак не спасает.

Но тут ещё не всё с этим фрагментом :)

```
return string_split(++string,array_results);
```

Как вы думаете, в какой момент значение указателя `string` станет равным нулю?

Правильно, в этот!

```
if(*string == ' '){ string = 0; }
```