# Запись адреса в массив указателей

Tags: c

```
char *pointers_on_words[20];
char str[]= "First Second Third";

string_split(str,pointers_on_words);    

int string_split(char* string,char * array_results){
    static int word_count;
        if( *string == '\0'){ int k= word_count; word_count =0; return k+1; }//конец строки
        if( *(string-1) == '\0'){// если предыдущий символ \0 - значит началось новое слово
               *array_results = string;//запись адреса нового слова
               array_results++;
               word_count++;
        }
        if(*string == ' '){//заменяем пробелы на \0
                *string = '\0';
        }
    return string_split(string+1,array_results);
    }
```

Результатом этой функции должна быть строка, разбитая на слова разделеные \0 -символом.
И массив указателей array_results, в котором должны быть указатели на начало этих самых слов.

Но возникает ошибка при записи адреса в массив указателей.

Comment: Я же вам уже давал готовый код, что у вас опять какая-то ерунда? См. мой ответ http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/596834/195342

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы объявили второй параметр, как имеющий тип `char *`

```
int string_split(char* string,char * array_results){
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

поэтому по крайней мере в этом предложении

```
*array_results = string;
```

должна возникнуть ошибка компиляции, так как левый операнд присваивания имеет тип `char`, а правый операнд имеет тип `char *`.

Comment: Но array_results - это ведь массив указателей, как у него еще записовать адрес ?

Comment: @Hardc0re вы объявили параметр не как массив указателей, а как указатель.

Answer (score 0):

Второй параметр функции надо описать вот так:

```
char * array_results[]
```

Соответственно, код под условием переписать так:

```
array_results[word_count] = string;
word_count++;
```

Что, на самом деле, произойдёт при рекурсивном вызове функции со статической переменной, я представить не могу... Зачем это нужно? Ведь всё решается методом линейного просмотра строки за один проход.

Answer (score -1):

Это не ошибка, а предупреждение. Необходимо сделать конвертацию типа

Comment: Где предупреждение??